# V6 React Router Dom Routes are not working

Tags: mysql, reactjs, mamp, react-dom

I am trying to build a React register and login with JWT tokens and I am hitting a wall.

When I click on the register button it should take me to the login. And from there I should be able to login and see the dashboard.

When I click on register, nothing happens. I replaced useHistory with useNavigate and .history.push with navigate but still nothing.

I'm using MAMP for my db.

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Register from "./components/Register";
 
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<><Navbar /><Dashboard /></>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import "bulma/css/bulma.css";
import axios from "axios";
 
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Dashboard.js

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
 
const Dashboard = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    const [expire, setExpire] = useState('');
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
 
    useEffect(() => {
        refreshToken();
        getUsers();
    }, []);
 
    const refreshToken = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3306/token');
            setToken(response.data.accessToken);
            const decoded = jwt_decode(response.data.accessToken);
            setName(decoded.name);
            setExpire(decoded.exp);
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                navigate("/");
            }
        }
    }
 
    const axiosJWT = axios.create();
 
    axiosJWT.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        if (expire * 1000 < currentDate.getTime()) {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3306/token');
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.accessToken}`;
            setToken(response.data.accessToken);
            const decoded = jwt_decode(response.data.accessToken);
            setName(decoded.name);
            setExpire(decoded.exp);
        }
        return config;
    }, (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
 
    const getUsers = async () => {
        const response = await axiosJWT.get('http://localhost:3306/users', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
        setUsers(response.data);
    }
 
    return (
        <div className="container mt-5">
            <h1>Welcome Back: {name}</h1>
            <table className="table is-striped is-fullwidth">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {users.map((user, index) => (
                        <tr key={user.id}>
                            <td>{index + 1}</td>
                            <td>{user.name}</td>
                            <td>{user.email}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
 
export default Dashboard
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
 
const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
 
    const Auth = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await axios.post('http://localhost:3306/login', {
                email: email,
                password: password
            });
            navigate("/dashboard");
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
            }
        }
    }
 
    return (
        <section className="hero has-background-grey-light is-fullheight is-fullwidth">
            <div className="hero-body">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="columns is-centered">
                        <div className="column is-4-desktop">
                            <form onSubmit={Auth} className="box">
                                <p className="has-text-centered">{msg}</p>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <label className="label">Email or Username</label>
                                    <div className="controls">
                                        <input type="text" className="input" placeholder="Username" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <label className="label">Password</label>
                                    <div className="controls">
                                        <input type="password" className="input" placeholder="Password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <button className="button is-success is-fullwidth">Login</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
 
export default Login
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
 
const Navbar = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
 
    const Logout = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.delete('http://localhost:3306/logout');
            navigate("/");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
 
    return (
        <nav className="navbar is-light" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="navbar-brand">
                    <a className="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
                        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28" alt="logo" />
                    </a>
 
                    <a href="/" role="button" className="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
 
                <div id="navbarBasicExample" className="navbar-menu">
                    <div className="navbar-start">
                        <a href="/" className="navbar-item">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </div>
 
                    <div className="navbar-end">
                        <div className="navbar-item">
                            <div className="buttons">
                                <button onClick={Logout} className="button is-light">
                                    Log Out
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
 
export default Navbar
```

Register.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
 
const Register = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [confPassword, setConfPassword] = useState('');
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
 
    const Register = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await axios.post('http://localhost:3306/users', {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                confPassword: confPassword
            });
            navigate("/");
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
            }
        }
    }
 
    return (
        <section className="hero has-background-grey-light is-fullheight is-fullwidth">
            <div className="hero-body">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="columns is-centered">
                        <div className="column is-4-desktop">
                            <form onSubmit={Register} className="box">
                                <p className="has-text-centered">{msg}</p>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <label className="label">Name</label>
                                    <div className="controls">
                                        <input type="text" className="input" placeholder="Name"
                                            value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <label className="label">Email</label>
                                    <div className="controls">
                                        <input type="text" className="input" placeholder="Email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <label className="label">Password</label>
                                    <div className="controls">
                                        <input type="password" className="input" placeholder="Password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <label className="label">Confirm Password</label>
                                    <div className="controls">
                                        <input type="password" className="input" placeholder="Confirm Password" value={confPassword} onChange={(e) => setConfPassword(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <button className="button is-success is-fullwidth">Register</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
 
export default Register
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say nothing happens? Have you tried debugging the code? Do you see network requests happening or errors in the console? Does the register function execute? If you are in chrome f12 to debug

Answer (score 1):

I don't think need the '/' in the routes, and you can just navigate to "register" and "dashboard". Only use anchor tags when linking to external pages. For internal navigation use Link tags: `<Link to="about">About</Link>` or `navigate()` for buttons.

The snippet below is modified from my code. Before the user is signed in (not authorized), show your marketing pages and the sign-in / sign-up buttons. Show marketing page by default, and sign-in / sign-up buttons will navigate to "enter" or similar. The * catch-all route will catch this and show your sign-in/sign-up page. Also, if someone is coming from a bookmark the "*" route catches that and directs them to sign-up, which perhaps they bounce through and get to the intended destination.

Once user is authenticated, return the 'dashboard' routes.

Note how the dashboard routes are nested and there's a component that wraps them all (good for your navbar). You put `<Outlet/>` into that component and any nexted routes will render where the outlet is. Also, within those routes, navigation is relative. ie. you can `navigate(jobId)` and not `` navigate(`jobs/${jobId}`) ``.

```
const unauthenticatedRoutes = (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<MarketingWrapper />}>
      <Route index element={<MarketingHome />
      <Route path="*" element={<SignUpSignIn />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
)

const authenticatedRoutes = (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<DashboardWrapper />}>
      <Route index element={<Dashboard />
      <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
      <Route path="enter" element={<SignUpSignIn />} />
      <Route path='signout' element={<SignOut signOut={signOut} />} />
      <Route path="jobs" element={<JobsList jobId={jobId!} />}>
        <Route path=":jobId" element={<JobPage />} />
        <Route index element={<JobNew jobId={jobId!} />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
)

return (
  isAuthenticated ? authenticatedRoutes : unauthenticatedRoutes
)
```